# Why doesn't the Earth have a photon-sphere?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, planets

The Scwarzschild metric describes any Spherical body untill its surface, so any object may be considered as a black hole, untill we reach the surface i.e. if we can't observe the planet, there should be no difference between the planet and a black hole.

A Photon-Sphere is defined as a sphere of photons orbiting around a Scwarzschild black hole in an unstable orbit. So theoretically even all planets including Earth should have a photon-sphere, but we have never observed it.

Why doesn't the Earth have a photon-sphere?

Comment: I don't understand your first paragraph. What does "until its surface" mean?  No, planets are not black holes.

Comment: @BowlOfRed : I presume they mean "the _exterior_ Schwarzschild metric describes the _gravity_ of a spherical body up to the point of its surface". The Schwarzschild exterior metric, of course, is the one which has things like the photon sphere.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer yes, that is what I meant

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The Earth is not small enough for its mass.**

It is true that the full Schwarzschild exterior metric always has a photon sphere (and an event horizon) no matter the mass. However, this is the problem:

> describes [the gravity of] any Spherical body untill its surface

At the Earth's mass and size, that surface comes "too soon" for the part of the Schwarzschild exterior metric that has the photon sphere to be realized. Instead, the *interior* metric commences because you're now below the surface. The surface of Earth starts at 6371 km from its center. The Schwarzschild photon sphere *would* start at 0.000014 km.

Answer (score 10):

> Why doesn't the Earth have a photon-sphere?

Earth does not have a photon sphere because it is too big. The Schwarzschild radius for Earth is about 9 mm. So the photon sphere would be at around 14 mm. Since Earth is somewhat larger than 14 mm it does not have a photon sphere.

Answer (score 3):

Black holes create a space-time that is so curved that it’s possible for photons to orbit it. Note that space-time must be curved to such an extent. This should not happen for a planet like earth since the space-time surrounding the earth is nowhere near as curved as for a black hole.

You are correct that the mass of the earth enclosed by an imaginary sphere $r > r_{earth}$ will also be the same mass enclosed by $r = r_S$ (Schwarzschild radius) but the space-time surrounding the prior is nowhere near as curved as the latter.